# Proper Uninstallation of Java from Linux

Tags: java, linux, redhat, yum, amazon-linux

I have a `EC2` instance running `Linux OS(Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03)` on it.
By default, it had java installed in it.

When I do `java -version`, this is what is shown in the console :

```
java version "1.7.0_171"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment(amzn-2.6.13.0.76.amznl-x86_64 u171-b01)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM(build 24.171-b01, mixed mode)
```

However, I want to remove java from my `EC2` instance.

So, I tried the command

`yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64`

And it removed from my instance. As a verification, when I do `java -version`, it shows `bash: java: command not found`.

But when I do :

`yum list installed | grep "java"`

I can see the following packages installed

```
javapackages-tools.noarch                 0.9.1-1.5.amzn1              installed
tzdata-java.noarch                        2019c-1.73.amzn1             installed
```

Similarly when I do :

```
yum list installed | grep "jdk"
```

I can see the following packages installed

```
copy-jdk-configs.noarch                   3.3-10.3.amzn1               installed
```

Can anyone tell me what these packages`(javapackages-tools.noarch, tzdata-java.noarch, copy-jdk-configs.noarch)` are for? Also do I need to remove them to completely remove java.

Comment: I too had a similar doubt. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe these packages are a dependency for other packages in your system. What's the output of this cmd: "yum erase --remove-leaves javapackages-tools.noarch" ? or this one: "rpm -q --whatrequires javapackages-tools.noarch"